Solve an exercise $E(X|Y)$ with $Y=aX+b$ given that $E(X)=\mu$ and $Var(X)=\sigma^2$
I'm trying to solve an exercise $E(X|Y)$ with $Y=aX+b$ given that $E(X)=\mu$ and $Var(X)=\sigma^2$.
I would expect that $E(X|Y)=\frac{Y-b}{a}$
I went something like this $f(Y=y)=f(X=\frac{y-b}{a})$ (this being the density) so $dF_y=f(Y=y)dy$ and $dF=f(X=\frac{y-b}{a})dx$. Also $dy=adx$
Now, for every $A$ in the $\sigma$-algebra it must be true that:
$$\int_A E(X|Y)dF_y = \int_A ydF_y=\int_A yf(Y=y)dy=\int_A yf(X=\frac{y-b}{a})dy=\int_A a(ax+b)f(X=x)dx$$
$$=\int_A (a^2x+ab)dF$$
Now consider $A=[0, c]$ and taking derivatives
$$ \frac{\delta}{\delta c} \int_0^c (a^2x+ab)f(x)dx=(a^2x+ab)f(x)$$
so this would mean that $E(X|Y) = ayf(\frac{y-b}{a})$
Am I doing something wrong?

A short remark: clearly $Y = aX + b \iff X = \frac{Y-a}{b}$; taking conditional expectations on both sides gives you what you want immediately, since trivially $E[Y \mid Y] = Y$.
If you want an argument straight from the definition, $E[X \mid Y]$ is the $Y$-measurable random variable satisfying $\int_A E[X \mid Y]dP = \int_A X dP$ for all $A$ generated by $Y$; clearly $\frac{Y-a}{b}$ is $Y$-measurable and gives equality.
One of the issues with your argument is that you should be careful conflating the shared probability measure with the distribution of $Y$; you can do this since $Y$ is a bijective transform of $X$, but not blindly/in general.
